# Angular array display

Tags: arrays, angular

How can I display information like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vyYU.png)

this picture???

```
const DISH = {
  id: '0',
  name: 'Uthappizza',
  image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
  category: 'mains',
  featured: true,
  label: 'Hot',
  price: '4.99',
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  comments: [
       {
           rating: 5,
           comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
           author: 'John Lemon',
           date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },

       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
           author: 'Paul McVites',
           date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 3,
           comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
           author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
           date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },


       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
           author: 'Ringo Starry',
           date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },

 {
           rating: 2,
           comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
           author: '25 Cent',
           date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       }
   ]
};
```

Nothing seems to be working..

Answer (score 0):

Here is stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jvnlfw

You have to iterate `DISH.comments` using `ngFor` in angular.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of this.sampleData.comments">
  <p>
   {{data.comment}}
</p>
<span *ngIf="data.rating">{{data.rating}} star</span>
<span>...{{data.author}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you won‘t need „this“ in your Angular html template.

Comment: <mat-list *ngIf="dish">
<h3>Comments</h3>
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
  <h4 matLine> {{comment.comment}}</h4>
  <p matLine> {{comment.rating}}</p>
  <p matLine> 
    <span> -- {{comment.author}}{{comment.date | date}}</span>

    </p>
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>             This worked for me.

Comment: i have given simplest form of solution. This is good which you given @UsteenaMoon